# Is it possible to know what 都 means in "Subj + 都 + Predicate + 了"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, phrase, adverbs

In my lessons, I came across two different meanings for the adverb 都 dōu:

1. "Already" with the structure: `Subj. + 都 + Predicate + 了`, where 了 stands for completion of the predicate (see [Expressing "already" with "dou" in resources.allsetlearning](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22already%22_with_%22dou%22)).
2. "All" or "both" with the structure: `Subj. + 都 + Predicate` (see [The "all" adverb "dou" in resources.allsetlearning](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/The_%22all%22_adverb_%22dou%22)).

**I wonder if it is possible in some sentences to distinguish between these meanings without more context.** In particular, I'm thinking about the situation when the sentence has a final particle 了, such as:

> 她们都吃饭了。
>
> 1: They have *already* eaten.
>
> 2: *All* of them ate.

Maybe there is not much difference, but I believe in English there is a difference in the *emphasis*: in 1., the emphasis is on the *time* (they ate before expected); while in 2., the emphasis is on the *number of people*. For example, if this was a sentence said in a restaurant by a waiter on the phone, interpretation 1. could mean a particular table just finished eating then, while interpretation 2. could mean all tables finished eating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than context, stress can also be a clue. Typically when the construction is used to express "already" there will be stress on the verb (perhaps in an indignant tone!).

Comment: What about when it means *all*, is the stress in the subject?

Comment: @Puco4 When it means _all_, there's usually no particular stress, as it's not a very emphatic sentence. If you wanted to emphasize "all", you'd probably also change the wording to 他们**全部都**吃饭了.

Answer (score 3):

> *It expresses "already" with the structure: Subj. + 都 + Predicate + 了*

Only '了' indicates 'completion of a verb' in this structure

'都' in [Subj. + 都 + Predicate + 了]  mean 'even'.  Try write a sentence in this structure without 了, and you wouldn't say 都 expresses "already".

Example:

- "他(都)说 不知道" = "(even) he said he didn't know"
- "他(都)说 不知道 (了)" = "He (has already) said he didn't know" or "(Even) he said he didn't know"

> *It is used for "all" or "both" with the structure: Subj. + 都 + [Verb Phrase]*

The 'all' and 'both' meanings can only apply with multiple objects

Example:

- [A and B (都) + Verb Phrase] = [A and B (both) + Verb Phrase]
- [subjects (都) + Verb Phrase] = [subjects (All) + Verb Phrase]

For a singular subject, 都 cannot expresses the meaning of 'all' or 'both' . It can only expresses 'Even' or 'too/ also' (Cantonese)

Comment: I haven't found a reference where 都 can be considered as  'too' or 'also' but instead it can be translated as 'even' ([see this dictionary](https://dict.naver.com/linedict/zhendict/dict.html#/cnen/entry/06c58d0907294c249ce100c70086729a)), which also covers the point.

Comment: http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/329/ [3] [粵] [adv] also; too. Seem like it is a Cantonese usage of 都

Comment: I do not think here the 了 is [perfective](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/40507/25265) indicating *completion*, but instead it is a *change of state* 了 as it occurs at the end of the sentence.

Comment: I think it could be either

Comment: From *C. Li, S. Thompson, Mandarin Chinese. A functional reference grammar*: "As long as 了 occurs at the end of a sentence after any word other than a verb, it is easy to be sure that it is the CRS [Current Relevant State - i.e. the change of state] 了 [instead of the perfective 了]". In the sentence "她们都吃饭了。", 了 appears after the object 饭 and it can only be a change-of-state 了.